# Basic Rails 404 Error Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, http-status-code-404

I have been looking for a simple answer to this for a ridiculously long time and it seems like this has to be so plainly obvious and simple because no one has an easy, idiot proof tutorial.

Anyway, all I want to do is to have a single 404.html static page that loads whenever ANY error is thrown.  Ideally this should only happen in production and staging.

I feel like this should be the easiest thing to do...  but I can't figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Good question @chishomer, I given best answer. Check that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447627/basic-rails-404-error-page/8987083#answer-8987083

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in your `ApplicationController`

```
unless  ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_404
end

private

  def render_404
    render :template => 'error_pages/404', :layout => false, :status => :not_found
  end
```

now set up `error_pages/404.html` and there you go

...or maybe I'm overcautious with Exception and you should rescue from RuntimeError instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also wanted to add that there is an indepth writeup that I found on this topic

http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: it should work, though the documentation says you should use `Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` instead of `ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local`.

Comment: Any errors in your app will return 404 now, not 500 as is proper though...  And routing errors won't be rescued see https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6275-abstractcontrolleractionnotfound-should-be-rescued  Looking though I guess that IS what he asked, though it really shouldn't be done :)  I use an nginx rule to throw 404 for anything in /images that can't be found.

Comment: What should I put in the route file?

Answer (score 14):

I believe that if you run in production mode, then 404.html in the public directory gets served whenever there are no routes for a URL.

Answer (score 7):

If you run in production mode, 404.html,500.html,422.html files in public directory gets served whenever there respective error occured, pages from above will be shown.

**In rails 3.1**

We can use like below:
Rails 3.1  will automatically generate a response with the correct HTTP status code (in most cases, this is 200 OK). You can use the :status option to change this:

> render :status => 500
>
> render :status => :forbidden

`Rails understands both numeric and symbolic status codes.`

[Fore more information see this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it. In my `application_controller.rb`:

```
def render_404
  render file: 'public/404.html', layout: false, status: :not_found
end
```

Then, in any controller where I want to render a 404, I do something like this:

```
@appointment = Appointment.find_by(id: params[:appointment_id]) || render_404
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't get a 404 whenever any error is thrown because not all errors result in 404s. That's why you have 404, 422, and 500 pages in your public directory. I guess rails has deemed these to be the most common errors. Like Ben said, 404 will come up when it can't find something, 500 when the application throws an error. Between the two, you can cover a lot of your bases.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is configuring your `config/application.rb` with the following:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!(
      'MyCustomException' => :not_found
    )
  end
end
```

So that whenever `MyCustomException` is raised, Rails treats it as a regular `:not_found`, rendering `public/404.html`.

To test this locally, make sure you change `config/environments/development.rb` to:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

Read more about [`config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses`.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which wants to return a 404 when *any* error is thrown.