# How do I set a catch-remaining default route to a directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Perhaps simply due to lack of good keywords, I wasnt able to find any useful solution for a problem that should be almost trivial…

In my *routes.rb*, how do I tell: "If no other route matches **request**, then deliver /foo/bar/**request**"?

(Note: **request** ≠ '/')

To be more specific:

If *http://example.com/somedir/test/1/2/3* is not matched, try */for/bar/somedir/test/1/2/3*, just if that does not exist, deliver *APP_DIR/public/404.html*.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447627/basic-rails-404-error-page

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525715/custom-error-page-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanx, but i dont want any controller handle it, nor do i want a simple page returned. the request may be – for example – example.com/somewhere/dosomething.pl?a=1&b=2 and i want that delivered from /foo/bar/somewhere/dosomething.pl

Comment: Why don't you want a controller handling it? Controllers can dynamically decide where to render from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`match "/home/*request" => redirect{|params| "/foo/bar/#{params[:request]}"}`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing

Comment: this would only work if /foo/bar is accesible from the internet – wich it is not (and will not!) /foo/bar is local file system!

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible without pointing it to a controller action.