# Rails: How do I create a custom 404 error page that uses the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, asset-pipeline

There are many solutions for creating customized error handling pages, but almost none for  Rails 4:

- [Basic Rails 404 Error Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447627/basic-rails-404-error-page)
- [Dynamic error pages in Rails](http://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails)

The standard answer of encouraging people to modify `404.html` in `/public` doesn't work for me because I want to use the CSS theme that resides in the asset pipeline. **Is there a way that html files can access those styles defined in the asset pipeline?** If not, **is there a way to create a custom error handler that has access to the pipeline?**

Comment: I think on your second reference have what do you want. **but almost none for Rails 4** , Are you sure the second reference not work on rails 4? What you have done already?

Comment: I had the same question, but because of multi-language necessity.

Answer (score 55):

For Rails 4.1 I like [this answer, add an asset type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25303705/608359) better; however I have not tried it.  On Rails 4.0.8, these three references helped me:

1. [Dynamic error pages](http://web.archive.org/web/20141231234828/http://wearestac.com/blog/dynamic-error-pages-in-rails) is the second reference in the question.  This worked just fine for me.
2. [Custom error pages](http://agileleague.com/blog/rails-3-2-custom-error-pages-the-exceptions_app-and-testing-with-capybara/) may have cribbed from the first reference, or the other way around, but goes the extra mile by adding some information about testing with Capybara.
3. I did not do the Capybara testing because I didn't want to change the test configuration; however, [RSpec-Rails Request Specs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs) clued me in to test these requests independently and see that they complete and return the correct content.

What follows is a nutshell description of what is taught by the three references:

1. Add the following setting to `config/environments/production.rb`

   ```
   # Route exceptions to the application router vs. default
   config.exceptions_app = self.routes
   ```
2. Edit the routing configuration, `config/routes.rb` to direct the error pages to an errors controller

   ```
     # error pages
     %w( 404 422 500 503 ).each do |code|
       get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code
     end
   ```

   will route the 404, 422, 500, and 503 page requests to the `show` action of the `errors` controller with a parameter `code` that has the value of the status code.
3. Create the controller, `app/controllers/errors_controller.rb`.  Here is the entire content:

   ```
   class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

     def show
       status_code = params[:code] || 500
       flash.alert = "Status #{status_code}"
       render status_code.to_s, status: status_code
     end

   end
   ```

   My preference was to set a status message on `flash.alert`
4. Create the pages themselves.  I use `.erb`  Here is `app/views/errors/500.html.erb`

   ```
   <p>Our apology.  Your request caused an error.</p>
   <%= render 'product_description' %>
   ```

   So you see that you can render a partial.  The page renders with all of the layout boilerplate from `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` or any other layout boilerplate that you have configured.  That includes the `<div id='alert'><%= alert %></div>` that displays the status message from the flash.
5. Tested with RSpec by adding a test file, `spec/requests/errors_request_spec.rb`.  Here is abbreviated content of that file that shows a test of the 500 status page:

   ```
   require 'rails_helper'

   RSpec.describe "errors", :type => :request do

     it "displays the 500 page" do
       get "/500"
       assert_select 'div#alert', 'Status 500'
       assert_select 'div[itemtype]'
     end

   end
   ```

   The first assertion checks for the flash alert.  The second assertion checks for the partial.

Comment: There is only one problem with the asset pipeline solution. Each html file is suffixed with the digest and thus making it hard to find from Dispatcher::PublicExceptions. I advice people to try the one mentioned here.

Answer (score 8):

We've made a gem which does this for you: [`exception_handler`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler).

There is also a great tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843).

I also wrote an extensive answer on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess).

**Middleware**

```
# config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
```

**Controller**

```
# app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
class ExceptionController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :js, :html
  before_action :set_status

  def show
    respond_with @status
  end

  private

  def set_status
    def status
      @exception = env['action_dispatch.exception']
      @status    = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
      @response  = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```
# app/views/exception/show.html.erb
<h1>404 error</h1>
```

This is very simple version - I can explain more if you wish.

Basically, you need to hook into the [`config.exceptions_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) middleware, it will capture any exception in the `middleware` stack (as opposed to rendering the entire environment), allowing you to send the request to your own `controller#action`.

If you comment, I'll help you out some more if you want!

Comment: `class ExceptionController < ApplicationController`

otherwise error

Comment: has nothing to do with rails version. it's the convention. controller is called `NameController` and then you name the file `name_controller.rb`. Rails is looking for a `NameController`. If you call it only `class Name` it's thrown a `Unable to autoload constant NameController` (because he expects the NameController but can't find it)