# Static 404 page Rails 4: how to use the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 4.2.3 and am trying to customize the 404 error page in `public/404.html`. How can I include images from the asset pipeline?

There's an [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26286472/5086345) how to build dynamic custom error pages. However, as described there, it requires a whole lot of changes to settings that I, as a beginner, am not ready to take. All I want to do is in my 404 page to include 2 images that are in the asset pipeline. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your error page to use images from the asset pipeline, then you have two options:

1. Use dynamic error pages (I've written a tutorial [here](https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages)).
2. Monkey patch the asset pipeline to allow non-fingerprinted assets.

Since you are ruling out option #1 for now, I think the monkey patch is the way to go. Install the [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets) gem in your app. This will patch the asset pipeline so that it produces non-fingerprinted assets (in addition to the fingerprinted ones).

```
# Gemfile
gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"
```

And of course, don't forget:

```
$ bundle install
```

Then in your `404.html`, just refer to the asset as if it were a static file, like this:

```
<img src="/assets/my-image.png">
```

This assumes the actual image is stored here in your project:

```
app/assets/images/my-image.png
```

Comment: Looks like there are [talks about non-stupid-digest-assets functionality being moved to sprokets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49).  Great answer BTW.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind, that content of `public` folder is visible to anyone.
There for, following the convention, I would create `assets` folder (if you don't have it already), then `images` and `stylesheets`.
And create regular html page

```
- app
...
- public
  - 404.html
  - images
    - image1.jpg
    - image2.jpg
  - stylesheets
    - style.css
```

Then in your `404.html` you will reference it like so:

`<img src="./assets/images/image1.jpg" alt=""/>`

Answer (score 3):

Add the images to the public folder.

Use root relative path to the images on the public 404/500 html pages.

```
<img src="/my-logo.png"/>
```

Comment: This is so obvious I feel dumb for not thinking of it lol

Answer (score 0):

In a new application, routes that are not found are directed to the static html page found in `public/404.html`.  As you have found this is a `.html` not `.html.erb` file which means you have to do fancy stuff to access your asset pipeline.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of creating a dynamic page, the easiest way is to copy* the two images from your asset pipeline into `public/assets` (or a sub-directory) and then include them with:

```
<img src="assets/image.jpg">
```

*You may also be able to use a symbolic link but it may cause problems depending on how your production server is set up.

Comment: True, but my question is how can I include images from the asset pipeline? Images in the asset pipeline are stored with a hash (in Rails4).

Comment: Sorry about that, I understand the problem now.  I've updated my answer to try to answer it better.  Are you dead set on using the asset pipeline for these two images?  You can easily have those 2 images outside the asset pipeline and without causing problems.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to use them from the asset pipeline and wonder if there's an easier way then the one described in the post I'm referring to.

Comment: hmmm... I personally doubt it, but maybe someone else will prove me wrong!  This is the easiest way I can think of, good luck.

Answer (score -2):

in your 404.html add...

```
<head>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="simple.gif">
</body>
```

Comment: These URLs will not resolve in production because they need fingerprints